Transparent bridging over 802.11 wifi
After unsuccessfully trying to get wifi bridges from different vendors to work together, I came across a piece of MikroTik documentation that explains why transparent L2 bridging won’t work.
Basically, in standard 802.11, every frame has three MAC addresses: the two stations involved and the two radios involved. On the client end, the station and radio address are identical, whereas the AP needs to know which station to forward the frame to, which adds up to three distinct addresses.
Transparent L2 bridging would need to be symmetrical – both wireless transmitters would need an address for the station that the frame originated from (return address for response frames) and another for the station the receiving wireless AP should forward the frame to, which adds up to four addresses. There exists a specification for a four-address format, but it is not unambiguous enough to guarantee compatibility between any two implementations of it.
Now I am wondering if there is a way to do transparent L2 bridging with the three-address format. Let us assume one of the wireless devices is a plain AP, the other wireless device (which I’ll refer to as the client bridgehead) appears to the AP as a client.
When the client bridgehead forwards a frame on behalf of a connected station, it would do so with the station’s MAC address rather than its own. Similarly, it would accept incoming frames with a destination address of any of the stations it serves and forward it over its wired interface to the respective station.
Two problems need to be addressed for this.
First, the client bridgehead needs to know the MAC addresses of all stations on whose behalf it should forward traffic. This could be implemented in a fashion similar to how an Ethernet switch works, by learning which address goes on which side upon first encountering them. Every MAC address is assigned to the side on which it was last seen as the sender address. If the sender and the recipient are both on the same side, nothing is forwarded. If the sender and recipient are known to be on different sides (or one of them is still unknown), the frame gets forwarded. If the recipient is the broadcast address, the frame will always get forwarded.
Second, association needs to be sorted out. The client bridgehead has associated with the AP using its own MAC address, and the AP might not recognize the MAC addresses of stations connected through the client bridgehead. Before forwarding the first frame on behalf of a station, the client bridgehead needs to re-associate with the AP using that station’s MAC address. The client bridgehead would then have multiple associations with the AP – one under its own MAC, and one for each station it has forwarded traffic for. Should one of these MAC addresses “migrate” to the wireless side of the client bridgehead, the latter would disassociate for that MAC address. The same could be done if a MAC address expires from the client bridgehead cache. If authentication is needed, the client bridgehead would have the credentials and could reuse them for each client.
This should be almost completely transparent to all sides. Limiting factors I could imagine:

the number of clients the AP can serve (any station reached through the client bridgehead would appear as a new client to the AP)
whether multiple clients can use the same credentials to associate with the AP (not a problem with WPA PSK, but might be an issue with EAP if configured in this manner)
if a frame is sent to a station behind the client bridgehead which has never sent a frame, that station is not associated with the AP and the AP would not forward that frame to the wifi side – this would be remediated as soon as the station sends its first frame, causing the client bridgehead to associate with the AP on its behalf. Then again, most stations send network frames pretty frequently (any DHCP client sends frames as soon as it is plugged into the network, until it gets a reply).

I doubt I’m the first to come up with this idea – so quite probably either some vendor has implemented this already, or I have overlooked something that will break this approach or make it impractical. Does anyone know which is the case and either which vendors have implemented it or what deal breaker I have overlooked?
